# Include paths for imports in babel using webpack

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

Given a directory structure such as:

```
project
├───common
│   └───js
└───src
    └───js
```

is there any way to add *import paths* to webpack so that a script inside `src/js` can resolve code inside `common/js` if it cannot find anything else locally?
Something like the code below would include `common/js/CommonClass.js`:

```js
import CommonClass from "CommonClass.js";
```

This is easy to do for example with compass inside `config.rb`:

```ruby
add_import_path "common/scss"
```

Comment: This is not up to Babel, because Babel just processes individual files, it is up to whatever module loader you are using. Are you using Node, Webpack, Browserify, SystemJS? Need more info.

Comment: @loganfsmyth aye, I meant to mention webpack but obviously never did!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack accepts multiple resource roots into config.

```
//webpack.conf.js
module.exports = {
   resolve: {
      root: [__dirname + '/common', __dirname + '/src']
   }
};
```

Now webpack will search modules in both directories as well. Note that option works only with absolute paths.

See [webpack docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) for more information.

Comment: I can't edit this answer for some reason but the docs link is out of date. See [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#root) instead.

Answer (score 2):

As just-boris said, you can use `resolve` config. The exact setup is differes, depending if you use Webpack 1 or 2.

**Webpack 1**

```js
resolve: {
  root: [
    path.resolve('./client')
  ]
},
```

**Webpack 2**

```js
resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.resolve('./client'),
    'node_modules'
  ]
},
```

[Aliasing](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html#aliasing) is another useful feature, but I personally find above config easier.

See my guide on [ES6 Import Statement Without Relative Paths](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/es6-import-statement-without-relative-paths-e1511d794f18#.by4uk9rkw)